# How to build a cross-platform C++ library in Windows and Linux

Tags: c++, windows, gcc, makefile, cross-compiling

I am a Linux user and a beginner in C++. I am developing a small library with the following structure

- **src**

  - main.cpp
  - makefile
- **include**

  - Inputs.h
  - GenerateTabValues.h
  - Prototypes.h
- **data**

  - TabNodes.csv
  - TabWeights.csv
- **output**

  - **test1**

    - Results.txt
  - **test2**
    ...

In Linux I usually compile C++ using gcc and, when I have multiple dependencies, I use make with a makefile. Below the one for the current case

```
CXX = g++

CXXFLAGS = -g -Wall
DLIBS = -lm -lgsl -lgslcblas -lgmp -lquadmath

DEPS = ../../include
TEST1 = ../../output/test1
TEST2 = ../../output/test2
TEST3 = ../../output/test3

vpath %.h $(DEPS)

main: *.cpp $(DEPS)/*.h $(TEST1)/*.h
    g++ $(CXXFLAGS) -I $(DEPS) -I $(TEST1) *.cpp -o main $(DLIBS)

all: test1 test2 test3

test1: *.cpp $(DEPS)/*.h $(TEST1)/*.h
    g++ $(CXXFLAGS) -I $(DEPS) -I $(TEST1) *.cpp -o main $(DLIBS)
    ./main test1

test2: *.cpp $(DEPS)/*.h $(TEST2)/*.h
    g++ $(CXXFLAGS) -I $(DEPS) -I $(TEST2) *.cpp -o main $(DLIBS)
    ./main test2

test3: *.cpp $(DEPS)/*.h $(TEST3)/*.h
    g++ $(CXXFLAGS) -I $(DEPS) -I $(TEST3) *.cpp -o main $(DLIBS)
    ./main test3

clean:
    rm -f main
```

I must now make my library cross-platform and able to compile and run on Windows.

Ideally I would like to retain the same structure and perhaps add a **build** folder containing **linux** and **win** subfolders with the former having the aforementioned makefile. However I am not sure on how to compile it on Windows.

Is there an equivalent to make in Windows? Should I use MSVC with MinGW? Any help or suggestion on which might be the best approach for flexible portability and cross-compilation?

Comment: Use [CMake](https://cmake.org) for: MS Windows, GNU/Linux, Mac OS, Android, ....

Comment: Do you put all your code for Inputs.h, GenerateTabValues.h and Prototypes.h in main.cpp?

Comment: I am not sure how it works though. I understand that CMake generates a makefile from CMakeLists.txt which is fine, but then how would I compile that makefile in windows?

Comment: The user of your library would use CMake to generate a project file or MakeFile for whatever compiler and/or IDE they are using. You would not ship the Makefile you generated by using CMake. That is an output that is usable in your system.

Comment: @StefanRiedel yes, all the header files are called in main.cpp.

Comment: CMake can generate a Visual Studio solution (.sln, .vcproj). Also, VS Code has a CMake Tools extension that integrates with CMake natively, also on Windows.

Comment: @papadeiv you mean "implemented" (not "called"). If it's about 50 lines of code, that may be fine, but IMHO that's a horrible design if it gets a bit larger than that. Of course that's off-topic...

Comment: @drescherjm okay, now I understand. I think I will try this route as it seems the most straightforward. 
Would you say it is common among open-source C++ devs to use CMake to achieve cross-compilation?

Comment: There are many open source libraries on github that use CMake for this purpose.

Comment: @StefanRiedel oh yes of course it is not an efficient implementation. As I said I am a beginner in C++ and still trying to wrap my head around simple issues.

Comment: CMake, for better or worse, has become the defacto standard build automation tool for cross-platform C++. Also it is no longer even the case that on windows you need to use CMake to generate .sln files. Modern versions of Visual Studio, out of the box, will just open directories containing CMakeLists.txt files like they are solutions. Microsoft still needs to do a little work to make it less rough around the edges but as of VS2019 it is pretty useable.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Use either MSVC or MinGW-w64, and make sure not to mix them.

But if you come from a Linux world you should stick with MinGW-w64 and maybe even consider [MSYS2](https://www.msys2.org/) which gives you a bash shell.

Check out my a minimal example for a cross-platform library here:
https://github.com/brechtsanders/ci-test

That project has both `Makefile` (not for MSVC) and `CMakeLists.txt` which work across platforms (not MSVC though).